# Making CentOS 7 USB host memorize mode selection for a particular attached device

Tags: android, adb

Is there a way to make CentOS 7 USB host somehow memorize the mode (e.g. MTP) selected in the mode selection menu that currently shows up on the phone every time upon attaching it? I recall having to select a desired mode for any particular device only once with Windows, so perhaps the same is also possible with Linux?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The choice which USB mode to use is up to the device, so which OS is running on the host is not relevant. The default USB mode can be set in Android developer options.

Comment: @Robert: thanks for your reply. I've just checked in Dev Options and it's already set to default to MTP there, so it's apparently ignoring it...